# How can I specify as_sitesearch in v2 of Google Site Search / Custom Search?

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

I have a Google Custom Search (that will be a Site Search in the future) and I'd like to use the snippet that Google provides:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '...';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>

<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

I need to restrict it to certain urls. When using the xml api, you can use the parameter as_sitesearch to specify this filter.. is there a way to do this with the code above?

with this I can now access the google.search.cse object before the search is loaded.. but I still don't know parameter:

```
<script>


var myCallback = function() {
  if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    // Document is ready when CSE element is initialized.
    // Render an element with both search box and search results in div with id 'test'.
    google.search.cse.element.render(
        {
          div: "test",
          tag: 'search'
         });
  } else {
    // Document is not ready yet, when CSE element is initialized.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
       // Render an element with both search box and search results in div with id 'test'.
        google.search.cse.element.render(
            {
              div: "test",
              tag: 'search'
            });
    }, true);
  }
};

// Insert it before the CSE code snippet so that cse.js can take the script
// parameters, like parsetags, callbacks.
window.__gcse = {
  parsetags: 'explicit',
  callback: myCallback
};


  (function() {

    var cx = '007407192365638902354:eyxoavi7oa0';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>



<style>
.gsc-control-cse * {
box-sizing:content-box;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Use a hidden field inside your search form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="as_sitesearch" value="your_url_here/directory">
```

Comment: I don't really have a search form.. where would I put it? The search form is rendered by the google javascript. It replaces the <gcse:search>-tag

Comment: Sorry, you just editted your code. if you look into the API documentation https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference, you can use the options to define the variable right?

Comment: yes, this was just an additional option... I think I just don't see it yet (maybe a bit of sleep will help ;)) - for the documentation, that you linked I would need to call the constructor myself.. but with the code I posted above, I already have a "google.search.cse.element" => do I need to start from scratch? (it seems that with the code I copied from google I always already have a initialized object)

Comment: You can add attributes to you search render.   google.search.cse.element.render  div: "test", attributes: {}, tag: 'search' });
However I cannot find the as_sitesearch attribute equivalent.

Comment: check https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes

Comment: yes, seen this as well.. but as you say.. => no as_sitesearch attribute

Comment: Maybe you can pass a querystring parameter to the search. Take a look into this discussion:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/es6Qhm8lhHg

Comment: it might have worked 2 years ago... doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same question.  The only way I have been able to restrict the search to a particular folder in Google Site Search version 2 is to hard-code it into the element:

```
<gcse:search as_sitesearch="www.mydomain.com/site1"></gcse:search>
```

It would be great if there was a way to add as_sitesearch via JavaScript, like with version 1.

Answer (score -1):

To restrict to certain urls:

```
    <gcse:searchbox-only as_sitesearch="mydomain.com" resultsUrl="http://mydomain.com/search-results/" enableAutoComplete="false"></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

Be sure to replace mydomain.com with the appropriate domain that you want to restrict to.